# I need to compare two string to see if they match or are a near match

Tags: string, comparison, string-comparison, fuzzy-logic

I have a series of Company Names returned from a web scrape and I am trying to compare them against a table of other Company Names to see if they match or are a near match;

- Some Company Ltd.
- Another Company Limited
- This Ltd.
- Some Company Ltd.
- Another Company Ltd.
- That Limited

So comparing the two lists should flag the first two rows as matching, the second rows as near matching and the third row as not matching. From what I understand this is a Fuzzy Search but I was after some clarification on how best to go about achieving this? Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
A C implementation can be found in External links: Levenshtein in MySQL